# Что значит "and" в media запросе CSS

Tags: css

Что значит and в медиа запросе?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
...
```

}

Comment: [первая ссылка из гугл](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/) - листайте до логических операторов.... и почаще пользуйтесь гуглом :-)

Comment: Увидел. Спасибо!